# SQLite query using Python IS NOT NULL has no effect

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a query which is supposed to let me input two keys, and find rows where there are matches between those two (of which there are only one for each pair in the database).

```py
params = (searchword1, searchword2)
c.execute("SELECT primarykey, key FROM table WHERE key=? AND ? IS NOT NULL", params)
rows = c.fetchall()
print(rows)
```

The print statement here gives me every case where only the first condition is true (key=?/key=searchword1).

What am I doing wrong?

Additionally - what I want to do here is simply to verify whether the data entry exists or not based on the two parameters. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: You can't bind column name in your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot bind column names to a prepared statement in SQL, which would represent a security risk.  However, in your case, the expression `key = ?` would never match if the value being bound is `NULL`, so you don't even need the check `? IS NOT NULL`:

```
params = (searchword1,)
c.execute("SELECT primarykey, key FROM table WHERE key = ?", params)
rows = c.fetchall()
print(rows)
```